# What is best possible way out to sort records by aggregate value in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cql3

I have following data model for cars production data.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
        date date,
        color varchar,          
        modelid varchar,
        PRIMARY KEY ((color), date, modelid)
    )WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date desc);
```

I want to sort it by total column in cassandra, which I was expecting to be generated as follows:

```
SELECT color, count(*) AS total 
FROM cars 
WHERE date<='2017-12-07' AND date >'2017-11-30' 
GROUP BY color 
ORDER BY total 
ALLOW FILTERING;
```

But as I come to know Cassandra only support sorting by clustering columns and I can't keep aggregate value in table apriori, what is best possible way out to do this sorting?

Comment: I recommend doing this task by Cassandras driver rather than cqlsh.
for example, you read all data for a period of time you needed and then sort them manually. but if you have large value data, following the solution that presented by @alex-ott

Answer (score 1):

First thing - the query that you're using is very ineffective - by using `ALLOW FILTERING` you're performing scanning of data on all servers - this may work for small datasets, but won't work for big datasets. You need to model your tables around queries that you're planning to execute.

Coming to your question - you need to use either Spark to do it, or do a sorting inside your application.

You shouldn't think about Cassandra as SQL-like database - to use it you need to follow some rules about data modelling, querying, etc. I would recommend to take [DS220](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds220-data-modeling) course on DataStax Academy to learn about modelling for Cassandra.